# Install ubuntu touch on android PRIMO8 Thomson tablet via ubuntu touch ZIP file on sd card as an experimentation

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, sd-card

I want to try to install ubuntu-touch on an old tablet.

Is there a way to get a ubuntu-touch ZIP file which could be installed via an SD CARD put in the tablet using the install-from-zip-file root menu of android ?

I know this device is not listed. But it does not matter for this experimentation. My question is more focused on: where are ubuntu-touch files compressed as ZIP format ?

Comment: No, their is no flashable zip of touch for that device, I could not even find a community building roms for it. The only way is for you to build it yourself but that CPU is pushing it a bit.

Comment: @MarkKirby: "their is no flashable zip of touch for that device". Yes, for sure. Anyway, I want to try any ZIP files avaible for any other devices. Do you know where the list of avaible ZIP files is available ?

Comment: There are no official lists or anything, best place to look is here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch/android-ports

Comment: @MarkKirby: "There are no official lists or anything", hummm, it is not a good news. Maybe should I try to find an other way to try to replace android by an installation of Ubuntu-Touch on this tablet.

Comment: I don't know if you understand how mobile firmware works. It isn't like desktop, where you just need the proper drivers; someone actually has to build the desired firmware from source, including any drivers, kernel modifications, etc necessary to boot the device.

Comment: @Zacharee1: the only one thing I wanted to try with this experimentation, was to make running ubuntu-touch on this old thomson PRIMO8, only for web searches. Then, the only thing need is wifi connection, and a web broswer. Don't need anything else. Do you think it could work ?

Comment: @user301828 no because that's just not how mobile firmware works.